# json_decode return null i guess

Tags: php, json

I try to run this on my server:

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json"));
echo $ip;
$city = $details -> city;
echo $city;
?>
```

But, this print ip only.
Maybe a server problem or configuration?

Comment: What is the content of file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json") ?

Comment: What does `var_dump($details);` show?

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Maybe you don't have `url_fopen` enabled on your server? Enable error reporting with `error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to code a bit more defensively, if that site has no data for the ip address you give it, then it wont return any `city` property

This is a little safer

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json"));
echo $ip . ' ';
if (isset($details->city)){
    echo $details->city;
} else {
    echo 'data not available';
}
```

Judging from what it returned for my IP Address, the details it provides are not very accurate anyway